# Transform keyword parameters into association list in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

If I have a function or macro (I'll go with the macro) taking some keyword arguments, such as:

```
(defmacro mwe (&whole args &key name description &allow-other-keys)
  (pushnew (list-to-alist args) *some-var*))
```

If I want to say that all usages of mwe will be of the form:

```
(mwe :name name :prop1 value1 :prop2 value2)
```

How can I transform that easily into an alist (or maybe a hash-table, but I think that will be overkill for just 2-10 fields) for easier retrieval of keyword-arguments, using `assoc`?

Comment: If you just want easy retrieval, how about just using `GETF` with a `&REST` argument?

Comment: [`alexandria:plist-alist`](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html)

Comment: @jkiiski I didn't really think of `getf`'. As you see, that's my accepted answer. Also, not sure if this would be a different question..., but how could I let emacs/SLIME know of some mandatory key arguments on autocompletion, then? I think I'd rather go with the `&WHOLE` alternative.

Comment: @ssice You can have an argument list like `(&rest args &key name description)`. That way the given keyword arguments will be in the rest argument, but slime will still show them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GETF` to access key/value elements in a property list:

```
CL-USER 19 > (getf '(:name name :prop1 value1 :prop2 value2)
                   :prop2)
VALUE2
```

To convert a property list to an assoc list use for example:

```
CL-USER 18 > (loop for (parameter value)
                     on '(:name name :prop1 value1 :prop2 value2)
                     by #'cddr
                   collect (cons parameter value))
((:NAME . NAME) (:PROP1 . VALUE1) (:PROP2 . VALUE2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this (assumes the list is always even):

```
(defun list-to-alist (plist)
  (when plist
    (destructuring-bind (a b . rest) plist
      (cons (cons a b)
            (list-to-alist rest)))))
```

But I'd like to hear of any improvements or better ways to handle the case. I can accept an answer dealing with the `&whole`/`&key` situation in a completely different way if it makes more sense.

Comment: This also assumes that the list is sort enough that you can recurse. Tail recursion optimization is not required in Common Lisp.

Comment: If you meant *short*, I did state that in the OP.

Comment: There's no tail recursion here anyway, the result of the recursion is not immediately returned, it's used as the second argument for `cons`.